# Is "¿Qué hora es?" or "¿Qué horas son?" preferred?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, gramática

Admittedly, it has been a *very* long time since I've studied Spanish, but I distinctly recall that we always used "¿Que hora es?" for "what time is it?".

However, on a trip to the Dominican Republic, I asked our tour guide "¿Qué hora es?", and he corrected me, saying "¿Qué horas son?" is the internationally recognized proper grammar.  He mentioned that he was training to be a multilingual instructor of Spanish, English, and German, and that his phrasing was authoritatively correct per his training.

I find the phrasing of that strange, not only because I was taught the other way.  My literal translation of that seems to be "what hours are they?".  The tour guide's explanation was that the hours of the day are plural, and therefore using the singular is incorrect.  However, to my mind the "¿Qué hora es?" form is asking "what *hour* is it?", as in "it is the 5th hour", which makes more sense to me than "there are 5 hours".

Is one phrase correct and the other incorrect, or are both acceptable?  Also, is my understanding of the translations correct (i.e. "what hour is it" vs. "what hours are they")?  If "what hours are there" is the correct translation, why is "qué" used instead of "cuántas"?

Comment: "what hours are there?" would be "¿Qué horas hay?". "¿Qué horas son?" would be literally "What hours are they?" - not that it matters much.

Comment: True enough... edited accordingly.

Comment: I'm from Dominican Republic. The way it is taught in school is "¿Qué hora es?", but people here in DR tend to get confused because of the popular use of "¿Qué horas son?".

Comment: I'm from México and I always ask "Que horas son?" I recognize "Que hora es?" as the correct way though. So I think both are admisible.

Comment: In most parts of Mexico we use both forms. And it has also relation to the precise time in the moment. For example if it is 2 o'clock, you would use the plural form "son las dos" or "son las siete". But if it is 1 o'clock, you normally use the singular form: "es la una de la tarde".

Comment: España: ¿Qué hora es? incluso puedes decir ¿Tienes la hora?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

En España tú tienes razón en todo, ignoro lo que ocurra en otros lados. Aquí jamás oí «¿Qué horas son?» salvo en casos muy especiales:

In Spain:

1º Preguntar lo que marca el reloj en ese momento (siempre en singular)

> «What time is it?» = «¿Qué hora es?»

2º Como sinónimo de «How many hours are from 9 am to 8 pm?» (en plural)

> Llevo despierto desde ayer sábado por la mañana ¿Cuántas horas son? ¿Qué horas son?

3º Pero el plural sí se usa para hacer preguntas retóricas.

> ¡Eh, tú! ¿Qué horas son? Nosotros ya hemos cenado ¿Qué horas son estas de llegar a casa? ¿Te parece bonito tener preocupada a tu madre?

P.D. Laura me apunta un enlace a [la página sobre el término "hora"](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=hora2&lema=hora2) en el *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* de la RAE, donde viene que lo correcto es el singular, y que en plural se admite (aunque menos recomendado) y solo se usa en algunos sitios de América.

Comment: +1 if you want to add the RAE entry here is the link  http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=hora2

Comment: Gracias por el enlace, Laura. Soy nuevo en este formato web y no he puesto nunca un enlace, voy a ver si lo hago bien.

Comment: @Nexus He corregido el enlace para hacerlo aparecer de manera mejor. Cuando van a aceptar mis correcciones, vas a ver como lo he editado. :)

Comment: @Alenanno ¿Qué querías decir con "cuando van a aceptar mis correcciones"? diría que la frase no es correcta. Quizá "cuando aceptes mis correcciones" (?)

Comment: No sé quien acepta. Pero todavía no tengo la reputación que necesito para editar. Cuando lo hago, veo un mensaje "Wait until it is peer reviewed". No creo que Nexus acepte mi correcciones, sino que alguien lo hace mientras que no tenemos mods o pocos usuarios con una reputación alta. :D

Comment: En este caso sí me han preguntado si quería aceptar la modificación y lo he hecho. Supongo, solo supongo, que es porque soy el autor y tengo suficiente reputación como para que se me pregunte antes de que otros editen mis palabras. En mis primeros mensajes me lo editaron directamente sin tener que aceptar los cambios.

Comment: @Alenanno entonces podrías haber puesto "Cuando se acepten mis correcciones" así expresas que no sabes quien va a aceptarlas y que hasta entonces no se podrán ver los resultados de la corrección. Espero que no te moleste que te haya corregido.

Comment: @Laura No, ¡no me molesta! :) *Tienes que* corregirme cuando ves que he hecho faltas. :D Gracias. :)

Answer (score 7):

In Argentina, *"¿Qué hora es?*" is more usual, and sounds to me slightly better than the other one.  The [RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltConsulta?lema=hora) states:

> La pregunta que corresponde a la indicación de la hora se formula, en
>   la lengua general culta, en singular: **¿Qué hora es?** (en ella, la
>   palabra hora tiene el sentido genérico de ‘momento del día’). Su
>   formulación en plural (**¿Qué horas son?**) es admisible, aunque menos
>   recomendable, y se da con cierta frecuencia en algunos países de
>   América, especialmente en el nivel popular: «—¿Qué horas son, compa?
>   —Van a dar las cinco» (Campos Carne [Méx. 1982]). Solo es normal el
>   plural en la frase hecha de intención reprobatoria ¿qué horas son
>   estas?: «¿Cómo que qué horas son estas de llamar? ¡Pero si ha sido
>   usted quien...!» (GaMay Operación [Esp. 1991]). En la respuesta, el
>   verbo va en singular si se trata de la una (Es la una y diez) y en
>   plural en el resto de los casos (Son las diez y media; Son las dos
>   menos cuarto).

Answer (score 6):

I'm from Monterrey, Mexico and I've always heard:

- ¿Qué hora es?

If you say ¿Qué horas son? to people you know (friends or coworkers) sometimes they will mock and tell you: ¿Corazón? (¿Dear?), notice the **orazon** from Corazon and **horas son** from ¿Que horas son?.

So obviously the preferred way is the former.

Anyway as already stated in other answers it's very common to say:
"¿Que horas son estas de llegar?" when you want to express that you didn't come at the expected hour and it's too late.

Comment: +1 for "¡¿Que horas son estas de llegar?!" :)

Comment: Some people might also say "Las horas de mi corazón", hopefully only playfully and not in a pedantic tone

Comment: Perhaps this is an accurate description of Monterrey or even the north of Mexico, I don't know, but in some other regions there's nothing wrong with "qué horas son," and it's quite common.

Comment: Se deberían añadir los acentos a los "qué" interrogativos.

Answer (score 6):

I lived for two years in Honduras.  I heard **¿Qué horas son?** a lot more than **¿Qué hora es?**  In fact, I don't recall ever hearing a native Honduran say, **¿Qué hora es?** even though that's what I was taught to say while learning Spanish here in the U.S.

As a side note, my wife is from Brazil and the correct usage is **Que horas são?** (plural) in Brazilian Portuguese.

Comment: Small correction: The Brazilian Portuguese version is "Que horas são?". In Portuguese, we don't use the upside down interrogation mark at the beginning of a question and "que" never has an acute accent.

Comment: Thanks @AlanEvangelista, and you're right. I don't even know why I posted it with those, haha. Edited to reflect this.