# What is the difference between "es" and "está"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, verbos, cópulas

Can any one please explain to me when should I use *está* in place of *es*?

As far as my understanding goes *es* translates to *is* and *está* translates to *this*.

But sometimes I see that *está* is translated as *is*, too.

Comment: You wrote it incorrectly. _Es_ comes from the verb _ser_, and _está_ is a form of _estar_. **Ésta** can be translated to *this*, but it does not need the *tilde* anymore (i.e., it can always be written as **esta**).

Comment: the answer there could help you http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5617/why-do-we-say-que-hora-es-instead-of-que-hora-esta/5621#5621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two verbs representing English *to be*: *ser* and *estar*.

*Es* and *está* are conjugated forms of *ser* and *estar*, respectively. Precisely, it's the third person singular. *Está* is also the spelling for second person (tú) in imperative mood (cf [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=elbYf00qvVcRjg2FXzjo)).

The difference of these verbs is discussed a lot in every beginner book and in hundreds of tutorials on the Internet; for instance on [about.com](http://spanish.about.com/cs/verbs/a/servsestar.htm).
There are also a lot of question on that topic on this site. [Search for "ser estar"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=ser%20estar) or browse through the [cópula](/questions/tagged/c%c3%b3pula) tag.

That said, *ésta* (with the accent in the beginning) is also the spelling for the singular feminine demonstrative pronoun representing *this*.

It just happens to be like that. But there's no confusion because the demonstrative pronoun represents a noun (or–when used as an adjective–it precedes a noun) and the conjugated verb form is part of the predicate.

Ex.:

> As an adjective: Esta mujer está loca. <sub>This woman is crazy.</sub>
>   As a demonstrative pronoun: Ésta está loca. <sub>This one is crazy.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

"es" (verbo ser) is pretty much forever, part of the object.

*Él es ingeniero.*

"está" (verbo estar) is temporary.

*Juan está en África.
El Cairo es en África.*

I can think of very few cases in which you have to decide which one to use:

*Él es enfermo de SIDA.
Él está enfermo, con un resfriado.*

*Lex Luthor es un científico loco.
¡Cómo? ¿Estás loco?*

*La pared de la casa es roja.
Mi cara está roja de la vergüenza.*

*Jorge es calvo.
¿Viste a Jorge? Está casi completamente calvo.*

*Marte es un planeta muy frío.
El agua para cocinar ya está caliente.*

Comment: Some usages of "es" in this answer are not mainstream. We say "El Cairo *está* en África", because this is the norm for places. We say "Él *está* enfermo de SIDA", because it is temporary (It does not matter it is forever, being infected with AIDS is in no way part of the essence of a person).

Comment: just wondering, why is it "está chupado" in the colloquial phrase to say something is vey easy. One says, "es pan comido " to mean the same thing? Why the difference between the two verbs?